# Quote character in Postman URL path parameter

Tags: azure, postman

I am using Azure API Management to expose a REST API. One of the operations is a GET by partial name search, as follows:

```
GET /phonebook/namesearch/{{partial_name}}
```

where `partial_name` is a path parameter. I am able to verify this operation by invoking it in the Developer Portal and entering a search word. The search word can include a single quote, e.g. `o'neil`. I can also verify it by executing a curl command:

```
curl -H "apikey:apikey123"
     "https://<my-portal>.azure-api.net/phonebook/namesearch/o'neil"
```

But I am unable to execute a Postman test that involves the same URL as above, i.e. `https://<my-portal>.azure-api.net/phonebook/namesearch/o'neil`. This results in a HTTP 200 but with an empty result. Is there any problem with single quote in the URL field of Postman?

Comment: I already tried that (`&#39;`) too. The strange thing is that the curl command works but the exact same URL in Postman does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the Desktop version of Postman. The exact same test in Postman for Chrome (extension) works fine with the URL: `https://<my-portal>.azure-api.net/phonebook/namesearch/o'neil`. No need to escape anything. I will contact Postman team regarding this anomaly. For now, my problem is resolved, since I switched to using the extension.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the postman are you using?

Have you tried `\u0027` or  `\'`?

Comment: I am using the Desktop version of Postman (for Mac) - Version 4.10.3 (4.10.3). I tried both `\u0027` and `\'` and I get a _404 Resource Not Found_.